# Proof that T*T is non-negative on linear transformations

Tags: linear-transformations, adjoint-operators

I've been doing a few problems and ran upon one I've tried to solve with no luck:

Let $T: V \to W$ be a linear transformation and $T^*$ be its adjoint, prove that $T^*T$ is non-negative.

Most of the things I've tried have just gotten me more confused and nowhere near a valid proof.

Comment: What have you tried? This question is not terribly complicated. First, what does it mean to you, to say that "$T^* T$ is non-negative"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T^*$ has the propety that: $$\langle T(v),w \rangle =\langle v,T^*(w)\rangle,\;\; \forall v,w\in V$$
I remember that a non-negative linear trasformation $L:V\to V$ is such that:
$$\langle L(v),v\rangle\geq 0,\;\; \forall v \in V $$
in our case, we have:
$$\langle v,T^*(T(v)) \rangle=\langle T(v),T(v) \rangle\geq 0$$
where i use the positivity of the inner product.